# TextBox restricted to numbers

Tags: vba, numbers

I have a question, is it possible to limit a field in Telbox to a number consisting of 5 digits, e.g.
11111
22222

I tried to use a macro but it limits you to numbers only.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
     If Not IsNumeric(Chr(KeyAscii)) Then
          MsgBox "Enter a number!"   
          KeyAscii = 0 
     End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please take your time to properly format questions. Use code tags not quote tags for code.

Comment: Do you only care if the number is less than 99999? Would 2, 47, or 365 be valid inputs? Or is should the number be between 10000 and 99999? i.e. the number HAS to consist of five digits?

Comment: Thanks to MZiegaus, the macro works in UserForm but I have a problem running it in Sheet1. How to modify it so that it also works in the text field located in sheet1?

Answer (score 0):

You can respond to the Exit event in addition to the KeyPress event to accomplish this task:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
   If Not IsNumeric(Chr(KeyAscii)) And Not KeyAscii = 8 Then 'allow for backspace
      KeyAscii = 0
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   If Val(TextBox1.Text) < 10000 Or Val(TextBox1.Text) > 99999 Then
      MsgBox "The number must be 5 digits"
      Cancel = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to Brian M Stafford, the macro works in UserForm but I have a problem running it in Sheet1. How to modify it so that it also works in the text field located in sheet1?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me.
Rather than the .change Method i used the "beforeupdate" Method

```
Private Sub TextBox1_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) < 5 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter Values between 10000 and 99999"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.MaxLength = 5
End Sub
```

Maybe this helps

Comment: To slow. Sorry for posting after Brian M Stafford